# executing python scripts from a server

Tags: python

I have some python scripts on a server machine and i want to run those programs from a different machine on the same network. is there any way to run those programs remotely using a path somewhat like "http(or ftp):/10.10.5.18/path/script.py"

i am at an internship and i have made some basic python programs working with csv files, txt files, apis, gmplot, databases, mysql, pymysql, sqlite etc.. We have installed IDLE on the server machine and also have put all the pythhon scripts on it. now, to prevent the company's employees from coming to me again and again to get their work done, i want to give them links to the programs so that they can do their tasks themselves. is that possible in a simple way?

Comment: Why can't they login to the server and run the scripts using `python scriptname.py`?

Comment: @SukumarRdjf the users are supposed to be from a non technical background and on non technical positions and i am trying to allow them to process their data on their own. for example there is a program which converts some data in a csv file, manipulates it, creates a new csv file and adds the manipulated data into it. i want the users to be able to just add the address to the script in the command prompt or browser, upload their csv file(used tkinker for this) and then the processing happens in the server and the output file is created and saved in the user's system

Answer (score 0):

You can ssh into the system and run your scripts. (Linux)

```
  #!/bin/bash

  ssh <my_user>@<my_host> "bash -s" << EOF
  # here you just type all your commmands, as you can see, i.e.
      python /tmp/test.py;
      python /tmp/test1.py;
      python /tmp/test2.py;
  EOF
```

Comment: could you please elaborate as i am not an expert at the language

Comment: Can you please say what you're exactly trying to do?

Comment: i am at an internship and i have made some basic python programs working with csv files, txt files, apis, gmplot, databases, mysql, pymysql, sqlite etc.. We have installed IDLE on the server machine and also have put all the pythhon scripts on it. now, to prevent the company's employees from coming to me again and again to get their work done, i want to give them links to the programs so that they can do their tasks themselves. is that possible in a simple way?

Comment: You can customize the above command for each script and give it to anyone provided they can access the server machine via ssh.

Comment: i am really sorry to sound like complete novice, but where should this part of code be written? i mean could you gime me any links to some documentation on this? also, please check out my comment on the question, that may be able to explain my issue better

Comment: Refer to this link - https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/ssh-tutorial-how-does-ssh-work

Answer (score 0):

You can run python scripts remotely with ssh, just like any other command on a server. For example, I put a couple of simple scripts to do addition and multipication on an account of mine on a server:

Remote file ~/steve/scripts/add.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

name, p1, p2 = sys.argv[1:4]
sum = int(p1) + int(p2)
print("Hi {}, {} + {} = {}".format(name, p1, p2, sum))
```

Remote file ~/steve/scripts/mult.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

name, p1, p2 = sys.argv[1:4]
product = int(p1) * int(p2)
print("Hi {}, {} * {} = {}".format(name, p1, p2, product))
```

And then you just run these via ssh, supplying the proper arguments just like if you were calling the scripts locally:

Command executed locally:

```
ssh app1.unstable "~/steve/scripts/add.py" Joe 24 100
```

Result:

```
Hi Joe, 24 + 100 = 124
```

Command executed locally:

```
ssh app1.unstable "~/steve/scripts/mult.py" Kathy 12 24
```

Result:

```
Hi Kathy, 12 * 24 = 288
```

The results show up in your terminal just like if you were running the scripts locally.  You could redirect the output to a file, or whatever.

Comment: is the syntax the following: ssh app1.unstable "path" #arguments to be supplied#?

Comment: app1.unstable is the address of the server - "path" is the path to the script on the server.  The args are passed to the python script when it is executed.  The resulting output is piped back to the local console. - the server address looks funny because I have shortcuts set up in my ~/.ssh/config file.  The full address of the server is app1.unstable.iddev.in.  The shortcut handles determining which user to perform the request as, and provides that user's credentials if necessary.  Using ~/.ssh/config can reap HUGE benefits for productivity, especially for non-technical users...

Comment: you could change 'app1.unstable' to be pretty much anything you wanted via an entry in the local ~/.ssh/config file. - I have definitions in there for things like 'docker', 'es' (for our primary ElasticSearch server), 'jenkins' for our main Jenkins server, etc.  - in this case, I just picked an arbitrary server I already had set up to use to put together an example for you.

Comment: ...also, you could adjust the PATH on the server so that you could just specify "add.py" or "mult.py" and not, as an end user, have to know the path to those scripts.  You could even drop the '.py' and get down to `ssh calculator add Sam 123 456` - and the name parameter is, of course, just a kinda silly thing to make the example more interesting.